# How to share reqwest clients in actix-web server?

Tags: http, web, rust, actix-web, reqwest

I'm building a web server with actix-web, and one of the methods uses reqwest to make HTTP requests to an external API:

```rust
#[get("/foo")]
async fn foo() -> impl Responder {
  let resp = reqwest::get("https://externalapi.com/bar").await?; # GET request inside server
  ...
}
```

To improve the performance, I want to reuse the client of reqwest, because it holds a connection pool, according to [the doc](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/struct.Client.html).
However, I cannot use `Arc` to share the client, because the doc also has the following statement:

> You do not have to wrap the Client in an Rc or Arc to reuse it, because it already uses an Arc internally.

How can I share the client across the function calls?
Or, should I use a different library to create HTTP request inside web servers?

Comment: can you post your solution. I'm in similar situation but the urls may differ. So I can't create the client and store it in actix's context ahead of server creation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually suggestion in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/struct.Client.html) is the solution:

> You do not have to wrap the Client in an Rc or Arc to reuse it, because it already uses an Arc internally.

Simply `clone` the client.

Please check the `Client` definition from the [source](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/src/reqwest/async_impl/client.rs.html#60):

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Client {
    inner: Arc<ClientRef>,
}
```

You can think `Client` as a reference holder

The inner type(`ClientRef`) has wrapped with `Arc` as the documentation says and `Client` has `Clone` implementation, since there is no other fields except `inner: Arc<_>`, cloning the client will not cause any runtime overhead comparing to wrapping it with `Arc` by yourself.

Additionally `Client` implements `Send` this means clone of clients can be send across threads, since there is no explicit mutable operation over `Client` then `Mutex` is not needed in here. (I said explicit because there might be an interior mutability)